# Ad integration in Java desktop app

Tags: java, integration, desktop, ads, banner

I'm developing a Java desktop application and I need to monetize the thing by putting an advertising banner like you would do on a website.

Google AdSense doesn't allow this, so I registered to Adfonic which has a wiki page deidcated to "Windows 7" (http://developer.adfonic.com/index.php/Ad_Server_API) but I think it's for Windows PHONE 7, the mobile OS and not Windows 7. 
It's still unclear if Adfonic supports ad banners in desktop applications, so I came here to ask.

How could I proceed?

Comment: http://adfonic.com/about/ - `Adfonic is the smarter buying platform for mobile` - i really don't think you've chosen the right company.

Comment: Do you know a desktop-oriented advertising company?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to proceed would be to contact Adfonic and ask them. Their site is oriented to phone ads.